# How to generete Sync Agent Key (New Portal)

Tags: azure, azure-data-sync

Does anybody know where is Data Sync Agent key generator in new azure portal?
Old examples that i find reference old portal

Comment: You can always switch back to the old portal. It is still functional.

Comment: Really? How?I didn't see green preview button!

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find some of the features in the new Azure portal (HTML version), you can always switch back to the old Azure portal (Silverlight version).

In order to perform a switch, click on *Previous portal* in top righthand menu

[image: Previous portal]

Answer (score 0):

that should be available in the new portal.

once you have added an Agent in the portal, you should find a link at the bottom that says "Manage Key"

[image]